# How to create multiple variables from a variable with a long raw in SAS

Tags: sas, sas-macro, proc-sql

I am having trouble creating multiple variables from one long row. See below example,

{"screenW":1098,"screenH":618,"touch":true,"OS":"Windows","UTCoffset":300}

I would like to create 4 variables using the above row:

1. Device_width (corresponds to response of "screenW":)
2. Device_height (corresponds to response of "screenH":)
3. Touch (corresponds to response of "touch":)
4. Device_OS (corresponds to response of "OS":)

Thank you!

Comment: Is the source a text file or a character string in an existing dataset?

Comment: Is your file JSON originally?

Answer (score 3):

The JSON library engine will parse json into data sets.

Example:

```
filename mydata 'c:\temp\mydata.json';

data _null_;
  file mydata;
  put '{"screenW":1098,"screenH":618,"touch":true,"OS":"Windows","UTCoffset":300}';
run;

libname info json 'c:\temp\mydata.json';

proc copy inlib=info out=work;
run;
```